# Trigger event only once within transition-group

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been struggling with transitions in Vue. As far as I know I have to use `<transition-group/>` to animate a list of elements. The problem is that I want to have a scroll animation AFTER the animation is finished. There are some transition events, `@enter`, `@leave`, `@after-leave`, that I can use.

But when I have ten elements in my list the chosen event gets called ten times (which makes sense). Is it possible to fire an event when ALL the elements within the `<transition-group/>` are finished with transitioning?

**Example code:**

```
<transition-group name="slide" @after-enter="afterEnter">
  <div
    class="appointment-list"
    v-for="(list, key) in appointments_"
    :id="`appointment_${generateKey(key)}`"
    :key="generateKey(key)"
    :class="getClassObject(key)"
  >
    <div class="appointment-list__time">
      {{ formatDate(key) }}
    </div>
    <ul class="appointment-list__items">
      <li v-for="(appointment) in list" v-bind:key="appointment.id">
        <AppointmentItem v-bind="appointment" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

**The reason why I want to trigger an event when all the items are done transitioning:**

I have another component that changes the `appointments_` data (using Vuex state manager). When the animation is finished I want to call a function that scrolls the selected element into the screen. I have a somewhat terrible solution, which is the `setTimeOut()` method:

```
setSelectedCalendarDate(event, date) {
  // #ashamed
  const delay = moment(date).isSame(this.selectedDate_, 'month') ? 0 : 1000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    VueScrollTo.scrollTo(`#appointment_${date.format('YYYYMMDD')}`, 500, { offset: -60 });
  }, delay);

  this.$store.dispatch('appointments/setAppointmentsByDate', date);
},
```

I hope someone knows the solution to my problem. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. Each time the `@after-enter` event gets triggered, I'm checking if the index is the same as the size of the `appointment_` list. When the outcome is truthy, it is time to scroll!

**Keep track of the current index:**

```
<transition-group name="slide" @after-enter="afterEnter">
  <div
    v-for="(list, key, index) in appointments_"
    v-bind:key="key"
    v-bind:data-index="index"
  >
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

**Code that scrolls component into view:**

```
methods: {
  afterEnter(element) {
    if (this.appointments_.length === Number(element.dataset.index) + 1) {
      VueScrollTo.scrollTo(`#appointment_${this.selectedDate_}`, 500, { offset: -60 });
    }
  },
},
```